# How to get value of textareas with different ids

Tags: php, jquery

I have been trying to get the value of a textarea.

Here is a little php:

```
   <table>
    for($i=0;$i<count($resp);$i++)
    {
      <tr>
          <td style="text-align:center">
               <textarea id="'.$i.'" name="motivo" cols="15" rows="2"></textarea>
          </td>
          <td style="text-align:center">
              <img src="imagenes/delete.png" title="Anular" id="nombre2" name="nombre2" onclick="myfunction(document.getElementById(\'motivo\').value)"/>
          </td>
     </tr>
    }
 </table>
```

How my id it's different I can't do this document.getElementById(\'motivo\').value, I tried with jQuery but I can't get it to work:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("img[name=nombre2").on('click', function() {
       var id = $(textarea).attr('id');
       var value = $(textarea).val();
       alert('id'+id+'value'+value);
     });
   });
```

Comment: There's a typo: Missing closing bracket in sizzle expression, should be `$("img[name=nombre2]")`

Comment: Better use a class to trigger the event, then in the event handler get the id of the element that triggered the event or simply work with `$(this)` which will be referring to that element in the context of the handler.

Comment: Your jQuery has all sorts of issues.  There's a missing closing bracket in the img selector, and `$(textarea)` *probably* needs to be `$('textarea')` but this doesn't make sense, since you want to *find* a given textarea.  What's the relationship between the image and the textarea? **Please show more html / markup**.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clean up your syntax and then traverse the DOM a little - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/t43Lb/

```
$("img[name=nombre2]").on('click', function () {
    var $textarea = $(this).parent('td').prev().find('textarea'); // up, back and down
    var id = $textarea.attr('id');
    var value = $textarea.val();
    alert('id ' + id + ' value ' + value);
});
```

Comment: Great @daniela! please accept the answer when you get a moment.

Answer (score -1):

Solution to your question has already been provided.

Use this html and css for better performance: **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nwe9z/)**

```
<tr>
    <td style="text-align:center">
        <textarea id="_'.$i.'" name="motivo" cols="15" rows="2"></textarea>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:center">
        <img src="imagenes/delete.png" data-id="#_'.$i.'" title="Anular" id="nombre2" class="imgbtn"/>
    </td>
</tr>


$('.imgbtn').click(function()
{
    alert ( $($(this).attr('data-id')).val() );
    alert ( $($(this).attr('data-id')).attr('id') );
});
```

Comment: How is this better performance? Plus, the OP is looking for the id and value from the textarea in the previous table cell, not the element being clicked.

Comment: It will, $($(this).attr('data-id')).attr('id'). In my case you are not traversing the DOM!

Comment: But you cannot get the info from the textarea if you don't traverse the DOM. You're only getting the info from the .imgbtn, which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: It's a selector map! you don't need to traverse DOM.

Comment: A selector map? Neither returns any data when tested. You have to traverse if you want the information from the textarea in the table cell previous to the cell where the button is.

Comment: Scratch that - I figured it out. I was letting the $ signs go to my head. this requires that the OP heavily modify their markup in order to work, which may not be practical. Sure, it removes traversal but in this case it is not that costly.